# XGBoost model performance reporting on validation data

Tags: r, logging, xgboost

I want to leverage the `early.stop.round` functionality of XGBoost to do non-overfit training. For this I use following code:

```
param2 <- list("objective" = "reg:linear",
                     "eval_metric" = "rmse",
                     "max_depth" = 15,
                     "eta" = 0.03,
                     "gamma" = 0,
                     "subsample" = 0.5,
                    "colsample_bytree" = 0.6,
                     "min_child_weight" = 5,
                     "alpha" = 0.15)

  watchlist <- list(train = xgb.DMatrix(data = train_matrix, label = output_train),
                  test = xgb.DMatrix(data = total_matrix[ind, ], label = as.matrix(output_total[ind, ])))

  bst <- xgboost(data=train_matrix, label=output_train, nrounds = 500, watchlist = watchlist,
                        early.stop.round=5,verbose = 2, param=param2, missing = NaN)
```

So as required I create `train` and `test` `xgb.DMatrix` for watchlist and pass it to `xgboost()`. I made sure `verbose` is there to print intermediate results. But with `verbose=2` I get log like:

```
tree prunning end, 1 roots, 1692 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes ,max_depth=15
[74]    train-rmse:0.129515
tree prunning end, 1 roots, 1874 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes ,max_depth=15
[75]    train-rmse:0.128455
tree prunning end, 1 roots, 1826 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes ,max_depth=15
[76]    train-rmse:0.127804
tree prunning end, 1 roots, 1462 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes ,max_depth=15
[77]    train-rmse:0.126874
tree prunning end, 1 roots, 1848 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes ,max_depth=15
[78]    train-rmse:0.125914
```

while with `verbose=1` gives me:

```
[74]    train-rmse:0.129515
[75]    train-rmse:0.128455
[76]    train-rmse:0.127804
[77]    train-rmse:0.126874
[78]    train-rmse:0.125914
```

But none of this gives me model performance at each step for test DMatrix. I have also tried without success:

1. `verbose=T` and `verbose=F`.
2. changing name of `test` DMatrix to `validation`

What I am missing to get desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently test dataset performance reporting could only be done using `xgb.train()` not with `xgboost()`. Relevant modified code (not copying `param` part above) looks like:

```
  dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = train_matrix, label = output_train)
  dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(data = total_matrix[ind, ], label = as.matrix(output_total[ind, ]))
  watchlist <- list(train = dtrain, test = dtest)    
  bst <- xgb.train(data= dtrain, nrounds = 500, watchlist = watchlist,
                        prediction = T, early.stop.round=5,verbose = 1, param=param2, missing = NaN)
```